# ! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \end{gather}

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
\begin{gather}
\sigma_1$ = $\dfrac{M_1.y}{I_x}$ + $\dfrac{F_z}{A}\tag{1}\\
\sigma_2 = \dfrac{M_2.y}{I_x} + \dfrac{F_z}{A}\tag{2}\\
M_1 = F_y.L_1\tag{3}\\
M_1 = F_y.(L_1 + L_2)\tag{4}\\
\sigma_3 = \dfrac{M_3.y}{I_y} + \dfrac{F_z}{A}\tag{5}\\
\sigma_4 = \dfrac{M_4.y}{I_y} + \dfrac{F_z}{A}\tag{6}\\
M_3 = F_y.L_1\tag{7}\\
M_4 = F_y.(L_1 + L_2)\tag{8}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the question?

Comment: You shouldn't use $ ... $ is a display math environment.

Answer (score 4):

- The immediate source of the crash is the presence of the four `$` symbols. Either get rid of them or replace them with `\$` -- in case you need to display `$` symbols, which doesn't seem likely at all.
- In addition, you should get rid of the eight `\tag` statements -- they're redundant. And, you should either omit the `.` ("period", aka "full stop") symbols entirely or, at the very least, replace them with `\cdot`. (I favor the first option.)
- You're in display math mode by default inside a `gather` environment. Thus, replace all `\dfrac` statements with `\frac`.
- Optional: Change all 8 instances of `=` to `&=` and replace `gather` with `align.
- Optional (but suggested by @egreg, and hence to be taken seriously): Make the vertical distances between the rows equal by inserting (typographic) struts in the lines with a `\frac` term. In the solution below, look for the definition and use of `\mystrut`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
%% Define a typographic strut:
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\frac{My}{I_y}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\sigma_1 &= \frac{M_1y}{I_x} + \frac{F_z}{A}\\
\sigma_2 &= \frac{M_2y}{I_x} + \frac{F_z}{A}\\
M_1      &= F_yL_1          \mystrut\\
M_1      &= F_y(L_1 + L_2)  \mystrut\\
\sigma_3 &= \frac{M_3y}{I_y} + \frac{F_z}{A}\\
\sigma_4 &= \frac{M_4y}{I_y} + \frac{F_z}{A}\\
M_3      &= F_yL_1          \mystrut\\
M_4      &= F_y(L_1 + L_2)  \smash[b]{\mystrut}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add `\vphantom{\frac{F_z}{A}}` to the lines with no fraction.

Comment: @egreg - Great idea! :-) I'll edit my answer to incorporate this recommendation.